# ubuntu allow local ip address to connect to other local machine using ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have two machines on a local network

192.168.1.71 has ssh port open

$ netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN

port open  --> tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN

Lines in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

ListenAddress ::

ListenAddress 0.0.0.0

# SCENERIO

$ ssh foo@localhost --> connects successfully

$ ssh foo@192.168.1.71 --> (from same server 192.68.1.71 timesout)

$ ssh foo@192.168.1.71 --> (from server 192.168.1.90 timesout)

Is there a setting in the ssh_config file I must add like a new "ListenAddress" or something?

Almost thinking this is could be a firewall issue within the network and nothing to do with the ssh_config file on the server. Thanks in advance!

Diego

Tried the commands that you all recommended, below are the results

sudo ufw status
[sudo] password for dango: 
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

22/tcp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)

diego@ubuntu3:~$ sudo iptables -L INPUT -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Are you using ubuntu's firewall? To check run: `ufw status` it should show Status: inactive if it is disabled. If it is enabled run `ufw allow ssh` to enable ssh through.

Comment: ....or, more generally, do you have some firewall rules that are denying your inbound SSH access on `192.168.1.71`? You can check it by yourself (on any distribution) with: `iptables -L INPUT -n`. Let us know...